# upload app to the server

Tags: python, django, django-cms

HI everyone I have a pretty basic question, I create a project in Django on my local server, I create several apps too, and now I want to move only the apps to one project in Django on a server.

To do that I copy the entire file of one of my apps, and I move to the server, where are many apps.

I modified my `settings.py` to add the name of my app in `INSTALLED_APPS`, and modified the file `urls.py` to add the URL of my app.

How I can see in the server the full path of the other apps, to see what happens with my own app.

I forgot something when I move the app to the server!

Comment: I'm a bit confused. Aren't you pushing to github (or something like that) and just pulling the repo on a server? In other words modify local, push to production git, and pull on server.

Comment: yes @reticentroot this server is like a preproduction server!

Comment: you shouldn't have to restart the server. Either create a branch or repo with the project you want to pull into the server (which contains all the apps you want) or sftp into the server and upload the app into the correct directory.

Comment: yes @reticentroot  I  shouldn't have to restart the server, I don't do it, sorry I remove from the question. But I move the folder of my app into  the correct directory, buy I need set the full path for this new app, I have no idea how to visualize it

Comment: cd into the folder on the server and type pwd to get the full path